# Laravel database error with passport on deployment

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm having the following error :
SQLSTATE[22023]: Invalid parameter value: 7 ERROR: invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "utf8mb4" (SQL: select exists(select * from "oauth_personal_access_clients") as "exists")

```
$token = Auth::user()->createToken('api')->accessToken;
```

Of course, i'm using heroku with pgsql, and my db configuration =>

```
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

  'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

The database works fine, except for this case.

Comment: Your config charset `utf8` but your inserted field charset is `utf8mb4` may be you edit recently, then reboot your server

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. In passport.php

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Passport Storage Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This configuration value allows you to customize the storage options
    | for Passport, such as the database connection that should be used
    | by Passport's internal database models which store tokens, etc.
    |
    */

    'storage' => [
        'database' => [
            'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

I change it to :

```
  'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

and then php artisan migrate. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

where is the file to do that?? (Passport Storage Driver). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file passport.php is generated by running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config`. This information is very difficult to find and it should be mentioned in the original answer (which is correct).